# BufferedReader multiple lines as one String

Tags: java

I am trying to read multiple lines from a file into an ArrayList as a String.

What I aim to do is to make it so the program reads from a file line by line until the reader sees a specific symbol (`-`  in this case) and saves those rows as one single String. the code below makes every row a new string that it later adds to the list instead.

```
BufferedReader br = null;
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String read;
while ((read = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] splited = read.split("-");
    carList.add(Arrays.toString(splited));
}
for (String carList2 : carList) {
    System.out.println(carList2);
    System.out.println("x");
}
```

Comment: You should search for string concatenation

Comment: Could you show an example of the input data, along with the output you're hoping to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check if the read line contains "-".

- If it doesn't, concatenate the line with the previous ones.
- If it does, concatenate only the first part of the line with the previous line.

This is a quick implementation:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String read;
String concatenatedLine = "";
while ((read = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] splited = read.split("-");
    // if line doesn't contains "-", splited[0] and read are equals
    concatenatedLine += splited[0]; 
    if (splited.length > 1) {
        // if read line contains "-", there will be more than 1 element
        carList.add(Arrays.toString(splited)); // add to the list
        // store the second part of the line, in order to add it to the next ones
        concatenatedLine = splited[1];
    }
}
```

Note the output could not be what is expected if a line contains more than one `-`.

Also, concatenating String using `+` is not the best way to do it, but I let you find out more about that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear for me what is the output you desire.
If you would like to have each customer on one string without "-"
then you could try the following code:

```
while ((read = br.readLine()) != null) {
String splited = read.replace("-", " ");
carList.add(splited);
   }
```